Transition effect is starting from TOP-LEFT corner but need it to start from left corner
Transition effect is starting from TOP-LEFT corner but need it to start from left corner
Basically I am trying to make it like a small loading bar which loads when I hover over the block.


.buttonFrame {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 100px;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(6, 78, 166, 1) 57%, rgba(3, 134, 203, 1) 75%, rgba(2, 156, 218, 1) 82%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  /* Added height transition */
}

.buttonFrame:hover .btn {
  /* Changed to target .btn on hover of .buttonFrame */
  width: 100%;
  /* Adjusted width for hover effect */
  height: 100%;
  /* Adjusted height for hover effect */
  background-position: 0 0;
  /* transform: scaleX(2); */
}
<div class="buttonFrame">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>




Where is left corner if not the top left corner?

Why are you transitioning height if you want it to come from the left side (not corner)?

background-size is animatable so there is no need to insert an otherwise spurious element into the HTML.
This snippet has one div which has a background initially with 0 width and that gets transitioned to 100% on hover.


.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(6, 78, 166, 1) 57%, rgba(3, 134, 203, 1) 75%, rgba(2, 156, 218, 1) 82%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
  transition: background-size 2s;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.button:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* transform: scaleX(2); */
}
<div class="button"></div>




As A Haworth mentioned in comment, setting the height only on hover and in the transition will make it change from 0 to 100%. You can remove it and add the height to the button.
Also, the z-index has no unit of measurement, it shoudl be z-index:100;
Keeping your code :


.buttonFrame {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 45%;
  /* z-index: 100px; */
  z-index: 100;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(6, 78, 166, 1) 57%, rgba(3, 134, 203, 1) 75%, rgba(2, 156, 218, 1) 82%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  /* transition: width 2s, height 2s; */
  transition: width 2s;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttonFrame:hover .btn {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  background-position: 0 0;
}
<div class="buttonFrame">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>



Note that you can make it with one element using after. Here is a snippet only with the needed properties.


.btn {
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn,
.btn:after {
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.btn:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 2s;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(6, 78, 166, 1) 57%, rgba(3, 134, 203, 1) 75%, rgba(2, 156, 218, 1) 82%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="btn"></div>



